# When I press buttons on a GUI how do I store the values of the buttons?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm writing a predictive text program and I've assigned String values to the buttons. Lets say I click 4 then 6 then 6 then 3. How do I get 4663? Thanks.

Comment: You could store each value from button in a java.util.List and build the results when you need them

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `JButton`s [`getText()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#getText%28%29) method which will return a `String` representation of the text on the `JButton`, from there it can be converted to integer etc or concatenated/manipulated:

```
JButton button1=new JButton("Hello,");
JButton button2=new JButton("world!");
...
String text=button1.getText()+" "+button2.getText();//getText of button 1 and 2

System.out.println(text);//Hello, world!
```

As for your exact problem:

> Lets say I click 4 then 6 then 6 then 3. How do I get 4663?

Id recommend declaring a global `StringBuilder` to hold the data and accumulating in each `JButton` method using `append()`:

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

..
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {//method executed on click
...
sb.append(((JButton)ae.getSource()).getText());//get the JButton text and append it
}
```

simply print `StringBuilder` by calling `toString()` on its instance

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the method I will use.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use a `StringBuilder` as a class member variable and append the values on each button click:

```
myStringBuilder.append(myButton.getText());
...
```

and get the full text when needed:

```
String numberString = myStringBuilder.toString();
```

`StringBuilder` works in a FIFO manner so will maintain the order in which the numbers are added.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help... you can display the values in a editText control or textview, doesn't matter,here I used an EditText control in Eclipse

```
EditText etView = (EditText)findViewById(R.Id.etView);

When you click button 4 -->> etView.Append("4");
When you click button 6 -->> etView.Append("6");
When you click button 3 -->> etView.Append("3");

463
```